# Making changes to web.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I want to change the checkInterval setting in web.xml.

It's commented out in my current web.xml. In what section of web.xml dpo I update in order that its recognised by tomcat ?

So in web.xml I have :

```
<!--   checkInterval       If development is false and checkInterval is   -->
  <!--                       greater than zero, background compilations are -->
  <!--                       enabled. checkInterval is the time in seconds  -->
  <!--                       between checks to see if a JSP page (and its   -->
  <!--                       dependent files) needs to  be recompiled. [0]  -->
```

How do I uncomment the checkInterval parameter so its recognised by tomcat ?

Comment: Can you not just uncomment it?

Comment: @Woody please see question edit

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example. Please consider that the default value is 60.

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>30</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to set the parameter "development" to "true" for this to work. I copied the whole servlet entry from the web.xml here. There might be other  tags, but "development" and "checkInterval" are the most important ones for your question. I would also restart tomcat after these entry changes.
checkInterval is the time in seconds the webserver takes to check if a jsp page was changed. If it is just you and a few other developers it is perfectly fine to set it to 1 or 2, just play with it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in an init-param as the other other answer, within the servlet section under the comment is in (as this is what the comment applies to), so:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>120</param-value>
  </init-param>
  ....
```